# PHP array in object converting to string (so far as I can tell)

Tags: php, debugging

I'm developing front-end code for a web application, and ran into an odd piece of trouble with a custom object.  When I request the object and use `print_r()` I get this (the object is a lot bigger; just cut it to the relevant code):

```
MemberInfo Object
(
    [meta_data] => Array
    (
        [email_recommendations] => true
        [email_updates] => false
    )
)
```

To change something in the MemberInfo object, I just update its properties and send it back to the backend with a second function.  So for instance, the page is loaded once (which gives us the object shown above), then I send a POST request with changes on a second load of the page.  During the second load, I fetch the object above, set one field differently based on the POST with something like `$memberInfo->meta_data['email_recommendations'] = 'false';` and then use that version of the object to populate the page after running the update function (which is something like `updateMember($memberInfo);`).  However, once I've changed the object property value `print_r()` shows me something different:

```
MemberInfo Object
(
    [meta_data] => {\"email_recommendations\":\"false\",\"email_updates\":\"false\"}

)
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very stupid; does anyone have a good idea of what I should be looking for?  I checked, and the backend code isn't passing by reference (the function call is `updateMember(MemberInfo $memberInfo);`) but I'm a little shaky on my PHP 5 object handling so I'm not sure what might be going wrong.

I don't expect in-depth debugging; I just need to know the general direction I should be looking for what is causing this change in a property that by all rights should be an array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: very strange... looks like the member has been put through json_encode()

Comment: Yeah; I think that's how it's being stored in the database, but I can't figure out why the array that I'm modifying would change itself like that (particularly since the function call isn't passing by reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so are you using the object after calling `updateMember()`? PHP5 objects are passed by reference by default, so if you're calling `json_encode()` on the `meta_data` property, it'll exhibit the behaviour you describe.

you may want to post the `updateMember()` function to confirm, but it sounds like that's what's going on.

ie:

```
class MemberInfo {
    function __construct()  {
        $this->meta_data = array(
            'email_recommendations' => true,
            'email_updates' => false,
        );
    } 
}

function updateMember($meminfo) {
    $meminfo->meta_data = json_encode($meminfo->meta_data);
    // do stuff
}

$meminfo = new MemberInfo();

updateMember($meminfo);

print_r($meminfo); // you'll see the json encoded value for "meta_data"
```

Comment: Thanks Owen!  I hadn't known that little tidbit (knew it was going to be some minor thing that I was overlooking or not aware of). I'll see about a workaround, or else decode the thing on my end after I've run the update function.